# Printing functions returning incorrect value

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have this C code and I struggle with the functions `printCol();` and `printRow`.
When I run the code and call for these functions to print a specific column or a row, they always return the second row or column.

EDITED: I know that many functions are nonsense, but i just started to learn C, please don't be rude...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printRow1(int *p1, int rowSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", *p1);
        p1 += 1;
    }
}

void printCol1(int *p, int colSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < colSize; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *p);
        p += 4;
    }
}

void reverseRow1(int *p2) {
    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%d\t", *p2);
        p2-=1;
    }
}

int arr[3][4] = {
    { 1,  2,  3,  4 },
    { 5,  6,  7,  8 },
    { 9, 10, 11, 12 }
};

void printMat() {
    int col = 3;
    int row = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < col; i ++) {
        printf("\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void printCol() {
    printf("Which column would you like to print? \t");

    int choiceCol;
    scanf("%d\n", &choiceCol);

    char buf = fgetc(stdin);

    if (choiceCol >= 1 && choiceCol <= 4) {
        printCol1(&arr[0][choiceCol-1], 3);
    } else {
        printf("An Error occured\n");
    }
}

void printRow() {
    printf("Which row would you like to print? \t");

    int choiceRow;
    scanf("%d\n", &choiceRow);

    char buf = fgetc(stdin);

    if (choiceRow >= 1 && choiceRow <= 3){
        printRow1(&arr[choiceRow-1][0], 4);
    } else {
        printf("An Error occured\n");
    }
}

void reverseRow() {
    printf("which row to reverse?: \t");

    int reversedR = scanf("%d\n", &reversedR);

    printf("%d\n", reversedR);
    reverseRow1(&arr[0][reversedR]);
}

void printMenu() {
    printf("\n");
    printf("You can choose one of these services: \n");
    printf("1. Print matrix tabular form. \n");
    printf("2. Print a specific row or a number of rows in sequence \n");
    printf("3. Print a specific column or a number of columns in sequence \n");
    printf("4. Get the elements of a specific row reversed \n");
    printf("5. find the number of prime numbers in a specific row \n");
    printf("6. Quit \n");
    printf("Please select one to try ");

    int answer;
    scanf("%d\n", &answer);

    int *an = &answer;

    switch (*an) {
        case 1:
            printMat();
            printMenu();
            break;
        case 2:
            printCol();
            printMenu();
            break;

        case 3:
            printRow();
            printMenu();
            break;

        case 4:
            reverseRow();
            break;

        case 5:
            /* code */
            break;

        case 6:
            printf("Bye!\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("please select carefully! \n");
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    char buf;

    printMat();
    printMenu();

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please help me understand why this is happening? They are always printing wrong column or row.

Comment: Start by adopting a conventional coding style and format your code in a readable way. Expecting others to read this is plain rude.

Comment: Aside? You should remove the trailing whitespace from the format strings such as in `scanf("%d\n",&choiceRow);` Please see [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string) And it's very rare that you need a kludge like `char buf = fgetc(stdin);` unless the input has stalled and you need to clear it, but since you never check the return value from `scanf()` the code cannot know if this happened.

Comment: ... if the trailing newline in the format string did remove the trailing newline from the input, then `char buf = fgetc(stdin);` is trashing the first character of the subsequent entry. Every use of `scanf` in this code is with `%d` specifier, which filter whitespace automatically, and so they all can be like `scanf("%d", &choiceRow);` and remove the other fluff.

Comment: There is a ton of stuff in the code presented that appears unrelated to the question posed.  Please trim it down to a [mre].

Comment: `int reversedR = scanf("%d\n", &reversedR);` is nonsense. `scanf` returns the *number of successful conversions* (or EOF), not the result of a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky little bug, the problem wasn't with your print functions, but with the way you are reading input. You use things like `scanf("%d\n", &answer);` which wants to read a `%d` and a `\n`. When you enter a number you have to follow it by an enter, which might lead you to believe you need to read the `\n`, but it doesn't go into the input stream. This is also why in your program you would need to enter the selection twice. The second time it leaves a number in the input stream which is wrongly read to choose the row/column. I have corrected these mistakes in the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printRow1(int *p1, int rowSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", *p1);
        p1 += 1;
    }
}

void printCol1(int *p, int colSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < colSize; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *p);
        p += 4;
    }
}

void reverseRow1(int *p2) {
    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%d\t", *p2);
        p2-=1;
    }
}

int arr[3][4] = {
    { 1,  2,  3,  4 },
    { 5,  6,  7,  8 },
    { 9, 10, 11, 12 }
};

void printMat() {
    int col = 3;
    int row = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < col; i ++) {
        printf("\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void printCol() {
    printf("Which column would you like to print? \t");

    int choiceCol;
    scanf("%d", &choiceCol);

    if (choiceCol >= 1 && choiceCol <= 4) {
        printCol1(&arr[0][choiceCol-1], 3);
    } else {
        printf("An Error occured\n");
    }
}

void printRow() {
    printf("Which row would you like to print? \t");

    int choiceRow;
    scanf("%d", &choiceRow);

    if (choiceRow >= 1 && choiceRow <= 3){
        printRow1(&arr[choiceRow-1][0], 4);
    } else {
        printf("An Error occured\n");
    }
}

void reverseRow() {
    printf("which row to reverse?: \t");

    int reversedR = scanf("%d", &reversedR);

    printf("%d\n", reversedR);
    reverseRow1(&arr[0][reversedR]);
}

void printMenu() {
    printf("\n");
    printf("You can choose one of these services: \n");
    printf("1. Print matrix tabular form. \n");
    printf("2. Print a specific row or a number of rows in sequence \n");
    printf("3. Print a specific column or a number of columns in sequence \n");
    printf("4. Get the elements of a specific row reversed \n");
    printf("5. find the number of prime numbers in a specific row \n");
    printf("6. Quit \n");
    printf("Please select one to try ");

    int answer;
    scanf("%d", &answer);

    switch (answer) {
        case 1:
            printMat();
            printMenu();
            break;
        case 2:
            printCol();
            printMenu();
            break;

        case 3:
            printRow();
            printMenu();
            break;

        case 4:
            reverseRow();
            break;

        case 5:
            /* code */
            break;

        case 6:
            printf("Bye!\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("please select carefully! \n");
            break;
    }
}

int main() {

    printMat();
    printMenu();

    return 0;
}
```

A few other things I noticed, your menu options for row and column are flipped, and your code assumes the size of the array in several spots (this is very bad practice). If the code should work with different sized arrays then you should be passing the size around, if not then you should use macros to define the size. There may be other issues I didn't notice, but the issue mentioned in the question is now fixed.

Comment: This is essentially what @WeatherVane said, but I am just now seeing his comment. Well, now you can see it changed in your code.